How can I prevent duplicate entries into a TSQL Temporal Table?
I have a temporal table linked to my main table in our SQL Server database. If a user updates a cell value without changing it, the temporal table logs this as a new line.
This causes 2 lines with the same information (but different timestamps) to be added to the temporal table. How can I prevent the 2nd line from being added, and only add lines that have real changes (all columns other than timestamps)?
I tried adding a unique index to the temporal table, but that is not allowed:

Cannot create UNIQUE index on temporal history table

This is not an issue of duplicates on the main table. There is already a unique index on it preventing duplicate rows. This is a question of preventing duplicate history rows.
Here is the table structure:
CREATE TABLE controls.slot_table
(
    -- Primary Key
    ID_auto INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,

    -- Columns
    control_source_ID           INT,
    index_in_PLC                VARCHAR(1700),
    part_ID                     INT,
    panel_rack_slot_combo_AF    VARCHAR(1700),
    card_type_AF                VARCHAR(1700),
    IO_points_used_AF           INT,
    max_points_AF               INT,
    module_number               INT,
    slot_comment                VARCHAR(1700),
    lookup_location_sector_AF   VARCHAR(1700),
    lookup_location_room_AF     VARCHAR(1700),
    calc_slot_percent_spare_AF  DECIMAL(20,10),

    -- Constraints & Foreign Keys
    CONSTRAINT FK_slot_table_control_source_ID  
        FOREIGN KEY (control_source_ID) REFERENCES controls.source_standard(ID_auto),
    CONSTRAINT FK_slot_table_part_ID            
        FOREIGN KEY (part_ID) REFERENCES part.part_catalog(ID_auto),

    --Additional SystemVersioning necessary columns
    modified_by     VARCHAR(1700),
    modified_date   DATETIME2,
    created_by      VARCHAR(1700),
    created_date    DATETIME2,
    date_start  DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    date_end    DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(date_start, date_end)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = controls.slot_table_history));
GO

-- Unique Filter on Main table
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS DUPE_FILTER_Slot_Combo ON controls.slot_table

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DUPE_FILTER_Slot_Combo
ON controls.slot_table (control_source_ID, index_in_PLC)
WHERE (control_source_ID IS NOT NULL) AND (index_in_PLC IS NOT NULL)


Add the table structure, please

Ok, I added it. Let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful.


a [mre], but info for tables controls.source_standard and part.par_catalog are missing.   2) "I tried adding a unique index"  How did you try that ?  Please share that info too!


Is the real problem that you are performing on update on a row but updating the values to the existing values? When I work on temporal tables, I perform updates if there is something to actually update.

What's a cell? Just don't update rows with no changes, or don't use temporal tables because i don't think you can prevent this behaviour

This does indeed sound like an XY Problem, instead of asking how to stop a temporal table doing what it should be doing after an UPDATE, you should be asking how to not do an UPDATE when you aren't changing anything.

Thank you all for the feedback. This appears to be expected and standard behavior of the temporal table. It seems the best course of action is to prevent the UPDATE command if there is nothing being changed.
